# pytest fixture to make an AIPClient that I have parameters for

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I am trying to make a fixture that returns an APIClient object that is authenticated for a user that I can pass a parameter to if I need.  I have a DjangoModelFactory object called `CustomerFactory` that can create a customer and a user, the user of which is created with a `UserFactory` factory.  I want to be able to access the data in the customer that is created, but also have a fixture to make an authenticated API request.  This `api_customer_client` is what I came up with, and it doesn't work.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def api_client():
    return APIClient()


@pytest.fixture
def api_customer_client(app_customer, api_client):
    def _api_customer_client(test_customer=app_customer):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(test_customer)
        api_client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f"JWT {refresh.access_token}")
        return api_client

    return _api_customer_client
```

I am calling the fixture with this test:

```py
def test_client_cant_view_users_without_token(self, api_customer_client, app_customer):
    client = api_customer_client(test_customer=app_customer.user)
    result = client(reverse("api:user-list"), format="json")
    assert result.status_code == 401
```

I keep getting the error `TypeError: 'APIClient' object is not callable`, and I can't figure out why.  I originally thought it might be having trouble going through the `api_customer_client` fixture and returning a different fixture, but I have tried to just use `APIClient` directly in the `api_customer_client` fixture, and that didn't work either.

I have another fixture that is nearly identical, except for the sub-method thing, and it works perfectly:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def api_user_client(user: User, api_client):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    api_client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f"JWT {refresh.access_token}")
    return api_client
```

I hope I didn't go on too long with the explanation, but is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a dumb mistake.  I was looking at the fixture as the problem and not the test.

I completely rewrote my test, but I think the issue was the line:

```py
result = client(reverse("api:user-list"), format="json")
```

should have said:

```py
result = client.post(reverse("api:user-list"), format="json")
```

I believe this code will still work, even though the code I ended up using was somewhat different.